# ElasticSearch nested: NullPointerException during has_parent query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having weird issue

```
http://  machinename:9200/1_exposureindex/riskitemsearch/_search/

    {
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "contractsearch",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "Name": "4l4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I execute this query I get null pointer exception

```
{
error: SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[zohpYnUKQNSpROOg6eER9Q][1_exposureindex][1]: SearchParseException[[1_exposureindex][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"has_parent":{"parent_type":"contractsearch","query":{"term":{"Name":"4l4"}}}}}]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }{[zohpYnUKQNSpROOg6eER9Q][1_exposureindex][0]: SearchParseException[[1_exposureindex][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"has_parent":{"parent_type":"contractsearch","query":{"term":{"Name":"4l4"}}}}}]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }]
status: 500
}
```

but same query works when I do has_child

```
e.g. 
http://   machinename:9200/1_exposureindex/contractsearch/_search/

    {
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "riskitemsearch",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "Name": "4l4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a complete [curl recreation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/help/) with also a few documents that you indexed to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, it was mapping issue. I had _parent set to InitCase where as actual parent is lowercase.

Regards,
VB